# Constraining camera on character with map bounds and fixed y position- SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, camera, sprite-kit, position

I'm currently working on a game that has a vertical tileMap and a character toward the bottom of the screen that can only be moved on the x-axis. Currently to make it look like the game is scrolling I gave my character a velocity of dx:500 to have him travel up the tileMap.

When I run the simulator the camera starts towards the bottom left of everything and then looks like it is catching up to my scene contents. How can I fix that?

I tried implementing a camera to track the player when he moves toward the edge of the map(on the x axis) and it works but just partially. How can I have a camera follow a node all the way until the edge of the scene and stop once it reaches the end? I can't figure out how to give the camera boundaries to stop at on the x axis.

Also, I want my player to be on the same y coordinate the entire game and just have him move horizontally(about 70% down on the screen). How do I implement my velocity to move him up the map, and still keep him on a constant y-axis value?

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var worldNode = SKNode()
var bgNode = SKNode()
var fgNode = SKNode()
var cameraNode: SKNode!
var background: SKNode!
var player: Character1Node!
var platform: SKTileMapNode!
var previousTranslateX: CGFloat = 0.0


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    setupNodes()
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    cameraNode.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)

    //Panning for dragging player
    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.dragPlayer(sender:)))
    self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

}

func dragPlayer(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    //retrieve pan movement along the x-axis of the view since the gesture began
    let currentTranslateX = sender.translation(in: view!).x

    //calculate translation since last measurement
    let translateX = currentTranslateX - previousTranslateX

    //move shape
    let adjustment:CGFloat = 2.0
    player.parent!.position = CGPoint(x: player.parent!.position.x + (translateX*adjustment), y:player.parent!.position.y)


    //reset previous measuremnt
    if sender.state == .ended{
        previousTranslateX = 0
    } else {
        previousTranslateX = currentTranslateX
    }
}



func setupNodes(){

    //Connecting variables to scene
    worldNode = childNode(withName: "World")!
    bgNode = worldNode.childNode(withName: "Background")!
    background = bgNode.childNode(withName: "Overlay")!.copy() as! SKNode
    fgNode = worldNode.childNode(withName: "Foreground")!
    cameraNode = worldNode.childNode(withName: "Camera")!


    //Platform physics
    platform = fgNode.childNode(withName: "Level1Map") as! SKTileMapNode
    let bodySize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 190)
    platform.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: bodySize)
    platform.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
    platform.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    platform.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0
    platform.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Platform
    platform.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    platform.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*", using: {node, _ in
        if let customNode = node as? CustomNodeEvents {
            customNode.didMoveToScene()
        }
    })

    player = platform.childNode(withName: "//character1") as! Character1Node

}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    let position = player.parent!.position

    //Platform Tiles
    let column = platform.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: position)
    let row = platform.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: position)
    let objectTile = platform.tileDefinition(atColumn: column, row: row)
    //print(objectTile)

    if let _ = objectTile?.userData?.value(forKey: "tile2"){
        print("jumping tile")
    }

    if let _ = objectTile?.userData?.value(forKey: "tile1"){
        print("platform tile")
    }

    print(player.parent!.position)


}

override func didSimulatePhysics() {
    cameraNode.position = CGPoint(x: player.parent!.position.x, y: player.parent!.position.y)
    self.centerOnNode(node: cameraNode)
}

func centerOnNode(node: SKNode) {
    let cameraPositionInScene: CGPoint = node.scene!.convert(node.position, from: worldNode)
    node.parent!.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:node.parent!.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x, y:node.parent!.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y), duration: 2.0))

}
```

Comment: In the update function, what happens if you use `player.position` instead of `player.parent!.position`, so the declaration would be  `let position = player.position`? I'm curious why you need to use the players parent position.

Comment: @MarkBrownsword i have to use player.position because i'm using a reference node to reference my Character1Node.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the camera node from GameScene.sks and the references in code. Make sure to remove "Camera" from the the selected camera in the attributes inspector on the right-hand side of GameScene.sks. Replace all instances of cameraNode within GameScene with the following:

Near the other variable declarations add:

```
var cameraNode: SKCameraNode!
```

In didMove(to view:...) add:

```
cameraNode = SKCameraNode()
camera = cameraNode
player.addChild(cameraNode)
```

This will cause the cameraNode to be relative to the player's position. It will follow the player around wherever it goes!

Comment: Downvoting an old answer that proposed a working solution without a reason is frowned upon